# Rust trait object in tuple --- expected trait object, found type

Tags: rust, traits

I have been reading chapter 17 in [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) and I have been trying to use trait objects in my code.

Could someone please explain why the function `test2` does not compile while the others do?

```rust
trait Print {
    fn print(&self) -> String;
}

impl Print for i32 {
    fn print(&self) -> String {
        return format!("{}", &self);
    }
}

impl Print for &str {
    fn print(&self) -> String {
        return format!("'{}'", &self);
    }
}

pub fn test1() {
    let mut v: Vec<(usize, Box<dyn Print>)> = Vec::new();
    let bxx = Box::new(0);
    let idx = 1;
    v.push((idx, bxx));
    
    for (idx, val) in &v {
        println!("{} - {}", idx, val.print());
    }
}

pub fn test2() {
    let mut v: Vec<(usize, Box<dyn Print>)> = Vec::new();
    let bxx = Box::new(0);
    let idx = 2;
    let t = (idx, bxx);
    v.push(t);
    
    for (idx, val) in &v {
        println!("{} - {}", idx, val.print());
    }
}

pub fn test3() {
    let mut v: Vec<(usize, Box<dyn Print>)> = Vec::new();
    v.push((3, Box::new("a")));
    
    for (idx, val) in &v {
        println!("{} - {}", idx, val.print());
    }
}




fn main() {

    test1();
    test2();
    test3();

}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba09496ef867c2fda04d71e288c889f2)

Comment: That's odd, converting bxx to a box of dyn print compiled successfully, maybe type inferring made bxx a Box of i32 and not a Box of dyn Print, but i still don't understand why it doesn't compile.

Comment: Only difference is `v.push((idx, bxx));` against `let t = (idx, bxx);    v.push(t);`, and the latter failed. Is it that when `let t = (idx, bxx);` the type of the tuple is determined by compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when boxing it is gonna take as a box of the espeficit type you are boxing. In your case would be `Box<i32>`. If you annotate the type specifically then it works:

```rust
pub fn test2() {
    let mut v: Vec<(usize, Box<dyn Print>)> = Vec::new();
    let bxx: Box<dyn Print> = Box::new(0);
    let idx = 2;
    let t = (idx, bxx);
    v.push(t);
    
    for (idx, val) in &v {
        println!("{} - {}", idx, val.print());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8062c3f2533336dd623080c748278b77)

Comment: Hmmmm... in that case, why did `test1` compile? Would `bxx` not be constructed as `Box<i32>` instead of `Box<dyn Print>` in test1 as well?

Comment: @fvall the same reason, in example 1 you push directly to the vector without the `t` so the type is elided in that case. In the second example you are creating  `t` so it is creating the type of `t` as `(usize, Box<i32>)`

Comment: Right. Not sure I fully understand, probably due to my lack of knowledge of elision rules. I will accept the answer since it indeed solves the problem. Thanks!